# Print RDLC Report without showing ReportViewer Control

Tags: c#, winforms, report, rdlc

I was wondering if is possible to send/print data from `DataGridView` directly to rdlc report without binding it to `ReportViewer`control.

There are many threads about binding dgv data to report viewer control.
I don't want to create another form with report viewer control, but use existing form with data on `DataGridView` and on print button to send the data to `RDLC` report and print it.

Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: [Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx)

Comment: That is a document printing and not .rdlc. Thanks, but I don't need that!

Comment: I need smth like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360326/how-to-create-crystal-report-using-datagridview-values-without-using-database-in, but without using report viewer control. Is it possible?

Comment: It seems you didn't read the article and codes. *This walkthrough shows how to programmatically print a report without viewing it, using the LocalReport object and the CreateStreamCallback callback function.*

Comment: Yes I read it few days ago. 
I tried with similar document printing by getting data from DataGridView and draw it using System.Drawing.Printing. 
But I had lot of problems to measure page content and go to next page. Then I gave up! But I don't know where the data.xml came from :( and how to generate it.

I have lot of existing forms. Most of them are using DataGridView to present data. I would like to create *.rdlc report for each form. Then in my form on print button send the data from the grid directly to the report and print it! Is that possible?

Comment: As another option you can set the `Visible`property of a `ReportViewer` control to `false` and then set it to load the report and when the report loaded completely (while the report viewer) is invisible, call `PrintDialog()` method of the report viewer.

Comment: I edited the question and removed the answer from question. Since the question title and content and the answer is about RDLC reports, putting an answer about CrystalReports in question is somehow confusing. If for any reason you want to post the solution also for crystal reports, please add it as another answer :)

Comment: This is old but, I work in RDLC and SSRS a lot. WinForms and WebForms version of ReportViewer.

If you have blank values in the preview but, they show up in the print view or if it's blank everywhere it could be the font that you are using. But, it's most likely a problem with the dataset or the report parameters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can print an RDLC report programmatically by using [`LocalReport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms255056(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) object and [`CreateStreamCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms254645(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) callback function. Here is a complete Microsoft docs walkthrough which you may find useful:

- [Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms252091(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

To make it easier to use, I've created a [Print extension method](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/print-rdlc-report-without-showing-the-reportviewer/) which you can easily use it this way:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Print();
```

Here is the extension method:

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;

public static class LocalReportExtensions
{
    public static void Print(this LocalReport report)
    {
        var pageSettings = new PageSettings();
        pageSettings.PaperSize = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize;
        pageSettings.Landscape = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().IsLandscape;
        pageSettings.Margins = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().Margins;
        Print(report, pageSettings);
    }

    public static void Print(this LocalReport report, PageSettings pageSettings)
    {
        string deviceInfo =
            $@"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Width * 100}in</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Height * 100}in</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>{pageSettings.Margins.Top * 100}in</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>{pageSettings.Margins.Left * 100}in</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>{pageSettings.Margins.Right * 100}in</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>{pageSettings.Margins.Bottom * 100}in</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        var streams = new List<Stream>();
        var currentPageIndex = 0;

        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, 
            (name, fileNameExtension, encoding, mimeType, willSeek) => 
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                streams.Add(stream);
                return stream;
            }, out warnings);

        foreach (Stream stream in streams)
            stream.Position = 0;

        if (streams == null || streams.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");

        var printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
        if (!printDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        else
        {
            printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(streams[currentPageIndex]);
                Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                    e.PageBounds.Left - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                    e.PageBounds.Top - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                    e.PageBounds.Width,
                    e.PageBounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);
                currentPageIndex++;
                e.HasMorePages = (currentPageIndex < streams.Count);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, adjustedRect);
            };
            printDocument.EndPrint += (Sender, e) =>
            {
                if (streams != null)
                {
                    foreach (Stream stream in streams)
                        stream.Close();
                    streams = null;
                }
            };
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

**Print with showing Print dialog**

Just in case someone wants to print with showing Print dialog, you can put a `ReportViewer` on form and set the `Visible` property of the control to false then pass data to the report and when the [`RenderingComplete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms251814(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event fired, call `PrintDialog`:

- [ReportViewer.PrintDialog Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms252179(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: I've added invisible CrystalReportViewer to my form and called PrintReport() method that opens print dialog. That's what I need. Many thanks Reza!!

Comment: Also future readers may find this post useful: [Loading .rdlc report in Reportviewer manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056855/loading-rdlc-report-in-reportviewer-manually)

Comment: Thanks Reza. The invisible trick is really neat. The extension method on the other hand is something else altogether.

Comment: This works great. Thanks! A window appears in taskbar for a second. Anyone know how can I avoid this?

Comment: I found a solution: just add printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController(); before printDocument.Print().

Comment: hey mr.Rezan ,
FoxLearn Stole from you this solution
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiTTgwoticY&t=152s