# print RDLC reports in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

In following code it gives me an error here, i dont have an idea what am i missing here. 
Error: 
 An unhandled exception of type   'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException' occurred in   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll Additional information: An error occurred during local report processing.
    Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
     {   
     public class Printanje : IDisposable
   {
    private int m_currentPageIndex;
    private IList<Stream> m_streams;

    public DataTable LoadSalesData()
    {
        // Create a new DataSet and read sales data file 
        //    data.xml into the first DataTable.
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(@"..\..\ivana1.xml");
        return dataSet.Tables["DataTable1"];
    }
    // Routine to provide to the report renderer, in order to
    //    save an image for each page of the report.
    public Stream CreateStream(string name,
      string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,
      string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }
    // Export the given report as an EMF (Enhanced Metafile) file.
    public void Export(LocalReport report)
    {
        string deviceInfo =
          @"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>";
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Warning[] warnings;
        m_streams = new List<Stream>();
        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
           out warnings);
        foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
            stream.Position = 0;
    }
    // Handler for PrintPageEvents
    public void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        Metafile pageImage = new
           Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

        // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
        Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
            ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
            ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
            ev.PageBounds.Width,
            ev.PageBounds.Height);

        // Draw a white background for the report
        ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

        // Draw the report content
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

        // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
        m_currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }
    // Create a local report for Report.rdlc, load the data,
    //    export the report to an .emf file, and print it.
    public void Run()
    {
        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        report.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Report.rdlc";
        report.DataSources.Add(
           new ReportDataSource("Raboti", LoadSalesData()));
        Export(report);
        Print();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (m_streams != null)
        {
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Close();
            m_streams = null;
        }
    }



        }
     }
 //and in my form1 im calling:

         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            using (Printanje demo = new Printanje())
            {
                demo.Run();
            }

        }
```

Comment: You may find this post helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34728429/3110834

Comment: Your code seems alright to me and the error you're getting doesn't provide enough information to help locate the problem. You'll have to debug this one on your own, or at least give more information like the exact breakpoint that throws the error. Does your report render correctly? Might not be a printing problem.