# Close Application after WebBrowser print

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, webbrowser-control

I tried to print formatted HTML using WebBrowser class. After the print, I want to close the application. If I tried to use close the application the printing is not working. I tried using the timer also nothing works.

Please find the code below.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
 var b = new Program();
 string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
 b.runBrowserThread("file://" + appPath + "/receipt.html");

}

private void runBrowserThread(string url) {
 var th = new Thread(() => {
  var br = new WebBrowser();
  br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
  br.Navigate(url);
  Application.Run();
 });
 th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 th.Start();
}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
 var br = sender as WebBrowser;
 br.Print();
 //Application.ExitThread();
 Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: [PrintTemplateTeardown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768296(v%3Dvs.85)) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've answered a similar question previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737374/1768303

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`PrintTemplateTeardown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768296(v%3Dvs.85)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is what you are looking for.
You can add a reference to `SHDocVw`. Then you have access to interfaces like `IWebBrowser2` and `DWebBrowserEvents2_Event`.

You can find `SHDocVw` as "Microsoft Internet Controls" in COM tab of Reference manager window.

You can subscribe `DocumentCompleted` event to know when the file/url load completed. You can print html document without showing print dialog by calling `IWebBrowser2.ExecWB`. Also you can subscribe to `DWebBrowserEvents2_Event.PrintTemplateTeardown` to find out when print completed so you can close the application:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SHDocVw;
class Program
{
    static System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var fileName = "http://google.com";
        browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
        browser.Navigate(fileName);
        Application.Run();
    }
    private static void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var iwb2 = (IWebBrowser2)browser.ActiveXInstance;
        var events = (DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)browser.ActiveXInstance;
        events.PrintTemplateTeardown += browser_PrintTemplateTeardown;
        var missing = Type.Missing;
        iwb2.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, 
        ref missing, ref missing);
    }
    private static void browser_PrintTemplateTeardown(object pDisp)
    {
        browser.Dispose();
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works!. I tried to print receipt but it leaving extra space and page number url everything. is there anyway we can remove it?

Comment: I can suggest two options. If you want to continue using html printing, try to create simple html out put or use printer friendly styles (using media queries.) If using RDLC is an option for you, you can use design RDLC report and to print, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34727037/3110834).

Comment: I'm designed in html only the design looks good. I have written couple of print queries also but still it's printing page number and leaving extra white space in the bottom

Comment: Just to be clearer, we need the HTML content (and styles) as [MCVE]. Also since it doesn't have anything to do with current post, I think it's better to post a new Question. Feel free to notify me if you asked a new question, I'll give it a look.