# Create a Tiff Bitmap file from a DatagridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, graphics, tiff

I want to create a Tiff file from a Datagridview. I was able to get the Datagridview to a Tiff file, however I just want the Rows and Columns and nothing else.

Is this possible without using 3rd party Tool?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"})


    Dim height As Integer = DataGridView1.Height
    DataGridView1.Height = DataGridView1.RowCount * DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height

    Dim bitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Me.DataGridView1.Width - 1, Me.DataGridView1.Height - 1)
    DataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.DataGridView1.Width - 1, Me.DataGridView1.Height - 1))

    'Save the Bitmap to folder.
    bitmap.Save("C:Development\DataGridView.Tiff")

End Sub
```

I dont want the Highlighted

[image]

Comment: Try using `DataGridView1.ClearSelection ()` before `.DrawToBitmap ()`.

Comment: Tried this it didnt work same result

Comment: You may want to consider [Creating RDLC report from DataGridView dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367119/3110834) and [Print RDLC report without showing ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34728429/3110834),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to consider:

1. The DataGridView Rows and Columns must be visible when the control is drawn to a Bitmap,
2. ScrollBars may be present,
3. The height of the Rows may be different, so we have to sum the height of all rows,
4. The same for the Columns, since each Column has it's own width,
5. CellFormatting may be in place, so we need to refresh the DataGridView before drawing it: rows that are not visible may not have been formatted yet,
6. There's a limit (32,767) in the Bitmap dimensions.

Call this method as follows, specifying whether you want to include the Row or Column Headers or exclude both, passing `True`/`False` as the **`ColumnHeaders`** and **`RowHeaders`** arguments.
The **`dgv`** argument is of course the DataGridView control instance that will be drawn:

```
' Prints the DataGridView including the Columns' Headers only
Dim dgvBitmap = DataGridViewToBitmap(DataGridView1, True, False)
Dim imagePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{NameOf(DataGridView1)}.tiff")
dgvBitmap.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Tiff)

' Dispose of the Bitmap or set it as the PictureBox.Image, dispose of it later.  
dgvBitmap.Dispose()
```

---

```
Private Function DataGridViewToBitmap(dgv As DataGridView, ColumnHeaders As Boolean, RowHeaders As Boolean) As Bitmap
    dgv.ClearSelection()
    Dim originalSize = dgv.Size
    dgv.Height = dgv.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow).Sum(Function(r) r.Height) + dgv.ColumnHeadersHeight
    dgv.Width = dgv.Columns.OfType(Of DataGridViewColumn).Sum(Function(c) c.Width) + dgv.RowHeadersWidth
    dgv.Refresh()

    Dim dgvPosition = New Point(If(RowHeaders, 0, dgv.RowHeadersWidth), If(ColumnHeaders, 0, dgv.ColumnHeadersHeight))
    Dim dgvSize = New Size(dgv.Width, dgv.Height)
    If dgvSize.Height > 32760 OrElse dgvSize.Width > 32760 Then Return Nothing

    Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(Point.Empty, dgvSize)
    Using bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(dgvSize.Width, dgvSize.Height)
        dgv.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rect)
        If (dgv.Width > originalSize.Width) AndAlso dgv.ScrollBars.HasFlag(ScrollBars.Vertical) Then
            dgvSize.Width -= SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth
        End If
        If (dgv.Height > originalSize.Height) AndAlso dgv.ScrollBars.HasFlag(ScrollBars.Horizontal) Then
            dgvSize.Height -= SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight
        End If
        dgvSize = New Size(dgvSize.Width - dgvPosition.X, dgvSize.Height - dgvPosition.Y)

        dgv.Size = originalSize
        Return bmp.Clone(New Rectangle(dgvPosition, dgvSize), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: I've made a small change, adding one parameter that allows to specify whether the `RowHeader` and/or the `ColumnHeaders` should be included (instead of including or excluding both)