# Character is not valid '$' in printing reportviewer

Tags: vb.net, printing, report, reportviewer, printdocument

I copied the code in this link
[VB.NET - Print RDLC Report without showing ReportViewer control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196115/vb-net-print-rdlc-report-without-showing-reportviewer-control).
By reza aghaei and run tge system.
But it gives me bunch of  error saying ' character is not valid '$' . I'm just a newbie here. Hoping someone could help me. This is for our project in school.  I am using vb.net 2010

Comment: I am using vb.net 2010

Comment: You need a more up to date version of Visual Studio. The interpolated string used in that code is not valid until Visual Studio 2014. You are over 20 years behind the times. VS is free for the download for students.

Comment: As a workaround look up how to use `String.Format()`

Comment: Thank you Mary for your suggestions.