# why print directly from rdlc/report viewer, the print output has a red marking in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, report, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm trying print directly from rdlc/report viewer but the print output has a red marking in vb.net

is there something wrong with the code `LocalReportExtensions`?

Please Guide Me.

Thanks

```
Public Module LocalReportExtensions
        <Extension()>
        Sub Print(ByVal report As LocalReport, ByVal printerName As String)
            Dim pageSettings = New PageSettings()
            pageSettings.PaperSize = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize
            pageSettings.Landscape = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().IsLandscape
            pageSettings.Margins = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().Margins
            Print(report, pageSettings, printerName)
        End Sub
        <Extension()>
        Sub Print(ByVal report As LocalReport, ByVal pageSettings As PageSettings, ByVal printerName As String)
            Dim deviceInfo As String = $"<DeviceInfo>
                    <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                    <PageWidth>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Width * 100}in</PageWidth>
                    <PageHeight>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Height * 100}in</PageHeight>
                    <MarginTop>{pageSettings.Margins.Top * 100}in</MarginTop>
                    <MarginLeft>{pageSettings.Margins.Left * 100}in</MarginLeft>
                    <MarginRight>{pageSettings.Margins.Right * 100}in</MarginRight>
                    <MarginBottom>{pageSettings.Margins.Bottom * 100}in</MarginBottom>
                </DeviceInfo>"


        Dim warnings() As Warning
        Dim streams = New List(Of Stream)()
        Dim currentPageIndex = 0
        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo,
                      Function(name, fileNameExtension, encoding, mimeType, willSeek)
                          Dim stream = New MemoryStream()
                          streams.Add(stream)
                          Return stream
                      End Function, warnings)
        For Each stream As Stream In streams
            stream.Position = 0
        Next
        If streams Is Nothing OrElse streams.Count = 0 Then
            Throw New Exception("Error: no stream to print.")
        End If
        Dim printDocument = New PrintDocument()
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings
        If Not printDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid Then
            Throw New Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.")
        Else
            AddHandler printDocument.PrintPage,
                Sub(sender, e)
                    Dim pageImage As Metafile = New Metafile(streams(currentPageIndex))
                    Dim adjustedRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(
                        e.PageBounds.Left - CInt(e.PageSettings.HardMarginX),
                        e.PageBounds.Top - CInt(e.PageSettings.HardMarginY),
                        e.PageBounds.Width,
                        e.PageBounds.Height)
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect)
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect)
                    currentPageIndex += 1
                    e.HasMorePages = (currentPageIndex < streams.Count)
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, adjustedRect)
                End Sub

            AddHandler printDocument.EndPrint,
                Sub(Sender, e)
                    If streams IsNot Nothing Then
                        For Each stream As Stream In streams
                            stream.Close()
                        Next
                        streams = Nothing
                    End If
                End Sub
            printDocument.PrintController = New StandardPrintController()
            printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName
            printDocument.Print()
        End If
    End Sub
    End Module
```

RESULT OUTPUT IN HARDCOPY

[image: RESULT OUTPUT IN HARDCOPY]

result output in pdf

[image: result output in pdf]

Answer (score 0):

according to recommendations from @dr.null

From

```
AddHandler printDocument.PrintPage,
                Sub(sender, e)
                    Dim pageImage As Metafile = New Metafile(streams(currentPageIndex))
                    Dim adjustedRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(
                        e.PageBounds.Left - CInt(e.PageSettings.HardMarginX),
                        e.PageBounds.Top - CInt(e.PageSettings.HardMarginY),
                        e.PageBounds.Width,
                        e.PageBounds.Height)
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect)
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect)
                    currentPageIndex += 1
                    e.HasMorePages = (currentPageIndex < streams.Count)
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, adjustedRect)
                End Sub
```

To

```
AddHandler printDocument.PrintPage,
                Sub(sender, e)
                    Dim pageImage As Metafile = New Metafile(streams(currentPageIndex))
                    Dim adjustedRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(
                        e.PageBounds.Left - CInt(e.PageSettings.HardMarginX),
                        e.PageBounds.Top - CInt(e.PageSettings.HardMarginY),
                        e.PageBounds.Width - 1,
                        e.PageBounds.Height - 1)
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect)
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect)
                    currentPageIndex += 1
                    e.HasMorePages = (currentPageIndex < streams.Count)               
                End Sub
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? Your solution to not getting red in the printout was to not tell it to print in red? If that's the case then there was no issue in the first place. The code was doing exactly what you told it to do and it was coder error to specify the wrong colour. That's not a question for SO and, rather than posting an answer, you should delete the question because it doesn't really provide any value.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , because if someone copies the code on this website and then they find a problem with the red marking so they can look for a solution on this website

Comment: If you delete the question, how are they going to copy the code? The answer only has value if the question remains but the question should not remain.

Comment: Using white pen to draw on white paper? Really? What happens if you delete this line? Also, the `adjustedRect` doesn't look adjusted on paper.

Comment: @dr.null , 
thank you for your response . `Using white pen to draw on white paper? Really?` 
I got the source code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196115/vb-net-print-rdlc-report-without-showing-reportviewer-control) . `What happens if you delete this line? ` 
I will try to delete that line of code `Also, the adjustedRect doesn't look adjusted on paper` 
So how about I ask for guidance from you

Comment: Trim a pixel from the `e.PageBounds.Width` & `e.PageBounds.Height`. ( `-1` ).

Comment: @dr.null , `Trim a pixel from the e.PageBounds.Width & e.PageBounds.Height. ( -1 ).` you mean `e.PageBounds.Width - (1), e.PageBounds.Height - (1))` i tried to delete this line of code `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, adjustedRect)` no problem anyway

Comment: `e.PageBounds.Width - 1`.

Comment: @dr.null , Sorry if I disturbed you, I have a recent post, I hope you can help me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77918509/how-to-filter-datagridview-with-multi-criteria-textbox-with-dapper-in-vb-net)