# I haven't set any border on rdlc report but after print it shows a red colored border. Can any border tell me how to remove this?

Tags: c#, rdlc

I haven't set any border on rdlc report but after print it shows a red colored border. Can any border tell me how to remove this?

[image: Here is the output]

Comment: Is the screenshot from a report viewer in ASP.NET or a PDF?

Comment: the screenshot is from a pdf

Comment: Try open it with Chrome just to make sure it's not from whatever PDF reader you're using. If not from the tool, you may reference my answer below to find where the red border is from.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the .rdlc file with notepad++.

Then look for the string `<Color>Red</Color>`.

Try to read the XML structure to make a educated guess of where the border is coming from.

I'd say this is either from a Tablix or the main report.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I came across a similar issue.

Check the code you're using to print the PDF.

If you're using the Print extension method from here [Print RDLC Report without showing ReportViewer Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727037/print-rdlc-report-without-showing-reportviewer-control) there's a line in the code to print a red rectangle.

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, adjustedRect);
```

Just remove that line and you should be good.